# Data URI not working in Chrome anymore, why?

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome

In asp.net MVC I was loading blobed images from my db this way. It was displaying correctly on all browsers.

using the following

```
<div class="blogImage">
    <a href="~/WaiGuoAtHome/ImageHtml/@Model.Id">
        <img class="img-responsive homePhoto100" src="data:image;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)" title="@Model.Caption" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Navigate to the following page in firefox, IE and Chrome. Same code but on Chrome the image doesn't display. 
http://jacksonjhayes.azurewebsites.net/WaiGuoAtHome/ImageHtml/3646

I don't think this is a size issue, the image on that page is very big, but I display smaller images elsewhere that are much smaller.

Comment: Try adding the complete mime type, `image/jpeg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@onetrickpony your idea did the trick. Thanks! To bad I can't just use whatever image type I want any more but that makes sense, and I think all my images are jpeg anyway.